# Redirecting a pointer by reference in a Binary-Search-Tree

Tags: c, pointers, binary-search-tree, pass-by-reference

Given the following structs:

```
struct TElem {
  int val;
};

typedef int TKey;

struct Node {
  TKey key;
  struct TElem *elem;
  struct Node *left;
  struct Node *right;
};


struct bst {
  struct Node *root;
};
```

And the two functions `bst_Search` and `bst_Insert`.

```
struct TElem* bst_Search(struct bst *T, TKey c, struct Node **posins)
{
  struct Node *q = T->root;
  posins = &(T->root);                      // (1)

  while (q)
    if (q->key == c)
      return q->elem;
    else if ( c < q->key) {
      q = q->left;
      posins = &(q->left);
    } else {
      q = q->right;
      posins = &(q->right);
    }

  return NULL;
}

void bst_Insert(struct bst *T, TKey c, struct TElem *x)
{
  struct Node **posins;
  struct TElem *v;

  posins = malloc(sizeof *posins);
  v = bst_Search(T, c, posins);             // (2)

  if (!v) {
    struct Node *q = malloc(sizeof *q);
    q->key   = c;
    q->elem  = x;
    q->left  = NULL;
    q->right = NULL;
    *posins  = q;                           // (3)
  } else {
    printf("Key exists %d\n", c);
  }

  free(posins);
}
```

And `main()` is "mainly"

```
  struct bst *T = malloc(sizeof *T);
  T->root = NULL;

  struct TElem *x = elem_New(10);
  bst_Insert(T, c, x);
```

I'm trying to *insert* a new element (`elem_New` is working fine) into a BST, using a helper function `bst_Search` to return a pointer to the right place to *insert*. *(1)* is called in first pointing `posins` to  `T->root` memory address. (as far as I could debug this is working fine).

Then `posins` address returns to caller function `bst_Insert`, since `bst_Search` found a place for it returning `NULL` at *(2)*. It goes inside the `if` statement sets `q` correctly. Then at *(3)*, I expect that where `posins` is pointing to (in this case the address of where T->root is pointing too) now should be redirected to the new tree node `q`. The equivalent to `T->root = q`, but using this call by reference.

Comment: When you search the tree to find the place to store the node you can't really return NULL and allocate in that place. Remember that the left or right pointer has NULL, so you cant return that and assign something to it or you will get a segmentation fault. A simple solution would be to return the parent and allocate on its right pointer, or replicate the search logic and add in the right place.

Comment: @Isac `bst_Search` returns `NULL` but isn't in the return value (stored in `v`) that I'm working in, I do use `posins` instead.

Comment: posins will have `NULL` from `posins = &(q->right);`. Remember that you exit when `q == NULL` which is implied that `q->left` and `q->right` was `NULL` in the previous iteration.

Comment: `posins` is practically meaningless.

Comment: BLUEPIXY @Isac , yes. Makes sense.. Working on it.

Answer (score 0):

because your "posins" isn't change when out your "bst_Search"

```
void test(int *p){
// g_c is a gobal int 
p = &g_c;
 printf("%X ",p);}
```

do your think  when call  test(int *p)
the value of p will change to point the g_c?  no, because the p is only a parameter and it don't change it value when out the proc

```
my english is poor  so i just hope the e.g. code will help your understand~ :)
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you were updating the q is wrong. Let us say that the tree is like this:

[image: BST example structure]

Now let us say you search for 10, `bst_search(10)`  (I have removed your parameters for sake of simplicity and understanding)

Then, this is what you did:

```
posins = 5 // I am writing numeric values instead of addresses for understanding

// Now
10 > 5
p = p->right // => p = 12
posins = p->left // => posins = 9, cause p is pointing to 12

Again, 10 < 12
So, p = p->left; // => p = 9
posins = p->left; // posins = NULL
```

This is where it goes wrong, you should have pointed to 9, but you are pointing to the left of 9, This is what you should've coded:

```
struct TElem* bst_Search(struct bst *T, TKey c, struct Node **posins)
{
  struct Node *q = T->root;
  posins = &(T->root);                      // (1)

  while (q)
    if (q->key == c)
      return q->elem;
    else if ( c < q->key) {
      q = q->left;
      posins = &q;
    } else {
      q = q->right;
      posins = q;
    }

  return NULL;
}
```

Please comment for any further doubts.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that calling arguments can not be updated by operations like `posins = &(T->root);`.

> 93) A function may change the values of its parameters, but these
>   changes cannot affect the values of the arguments. On the other hand,
>   it is possible to pass a pointer to an object, and the function may
>   change the value of the object pointed to.

So, if you want to change the calling variable as a value as `P` it must be `*P`.
i.e. `struct Node **posins` should be `struct Node ***posins`.

The overall code is shown below as a sample.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct TElem {
    int val;
};

typedef int TKey;

struct Node {
    TKey key;
    struct TElem *elem;
    struct Node *left;
    struct Node *right;
};

struct bst {
    struct Node *root;
};

int TKeyCmp(TKey a, TKey b){
/* return value :
** a = b : 0
** a > b : positive value
** a < b : negative value
*/
    return a < b ? -1 : a > b;
}
struct TElem *elem_New(int value){
    struct TElem *ep = malloc(sizeof(*ep));//check omitted
    ep->val = value;
    return ep;
}
void elem_free(struct TElem *ep){
    free(ep);
}
void print(struct Node *np){
    if(np){
        print(np->left);
        printf("(%d, %d)", np->key, np->elem->val);
        print(np->right);
    }
}

struct TElem *bst_Search(struct bst *T, TKey c, struct Node ***posins){
    *posins = &T->root;

    while (**posins){
        int cmp = TKeyCmp(c, (**posins)->key);
        if(cmp == 0)
            return (**posins)->elem;
        else if ( cmp < 0)
            *posins = &(**posins)->left;
        else
            *posins = &(**posins)->right;
    }

    return NULL;
}

void bst_Insert(struct bst *T, TKey c, struct TElem *x){
    struct Node **posins;

    if (!bst_Search(T, c, &posins)) {
        struct Node *q = malloc(sizeof *q);
        q->key   = c;
        q->elem  = x;
        q->right = q->left  = NULL;
        *posins  = q;
    } else {
        elem_free(x);//avoid memory leak
        printf("Key exists %d\n", c);
    }
}

int main(void){
    struct bst *T = malloc(sizeof(*T));

    T->root = NULL;

    bst_Insert(T, 5, elem_New(10));
    bst_Insert(T, 1, elem_New(21));
    bst_Insert(T, 9, elem_New(42));
    bst_Insert(T, 1, elem_New(99));//Key exists 1
    print(T->root);//(1, 21)(5, 10)(9, 42)
    //release bst
}
```